# Is it possible to freeze a version in SonarQube's time machine?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-web, timemachine

Is it possible to freeze a version in SonarQube's time machine and make this snapshot always visible in the history chart? For example I have tagged a version in Git as v1.0 and I want this to be always in the chart so I can compare it with the latest versions and track the progress. Is the only way to launch Sonar Maven each time on this version?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to set a version on SonarQube snapshot. You can then use this version in [the differential period](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views) including the leak period.

Note also that adding an event to a snapshot prevent the snapshot to get deleted from the history. Find more information about this in [History and Events documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/History+and+Events).

You can set a version to a snapshot from SonarQube UI in the history of project's analyses (project administration permission is required).

Comment: But how to assign a version to snapshot? Its under which option?

Comment: Log as a project administrator. Then go in {{Administration}} > {{History}}. Finally, on column "Versions" of the relevant snapshot click on "create" (or "update" if you want to modify existing one).

Comment: Can we assign version from history using "web Api" , I have around 40 projects and I want to assign versions to all?

Comment: Yes it is. Here is the documentation of '/api/event':
http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392183#WebService/api/events-Createaneventonaproject

Comment: Thanks a lot. The "differential period link is not working".

Comment: I am using web api but over there I cant find a way to assign versions to project. I am using sonarqube version 5.3. For reference https://nemo.sonarqube.org/web_api

Comment: Agree with you the API is not really clear on that. What you should know is that for a SonarQube project history a version is an event. It means that adding a version to a project analysis means adding an event to a snapshot. Find the related documentation [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392183#WebService/api/events-Createaneventonaproject)